# Cannot deserialize Json to object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

Here is my Json:

```
{"Username":"Test","ProductIds":"[30, 50]","RouteName":"ABCD"}
```

And here is my object:

```
public class SuggestMobileModel
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public List<int> ProductIds { get; set; }
        public string RouteName { get; set; }
    }
```

When I convert that Json to that object, I can receive the `Username`, `RouteName`, but the `ProductIds` is always null. It only works when I remove the quotation in `ProductIds` value, like this:

```
{"Username":"Test","ProductIds":[30, 50],"RouteName":"ABCD"}
```

What can I do now to deserialize successfully without removing the code? That Json is generated by code, so it always has that quotes.

**---EDIT!!!---**

Here is the Java code created that Json string. Does it has any error? It's using `org.json` library.

```
// 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlSuggestRoute);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("Username", User.getUsername());
            List<Integer> listProductIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            if (Cart.getCart() != null && Cart.getSize() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Cart.getSize(); i++) {
                    listProductIds.add(Cart.getCartItem(i)
                            .getProductAttribute().getProductId());
                }
            }
            jsonObject.accumulate("ProductIds", listProductIds);
            jsonObject.accumulate("RouteName", txtRoute.getSelectedItem()
                    .toString());

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the
            // content
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: Currently, I send this Json to Web API Controller and let it deserialize itself. I've also tried using Newtonsoft but it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't matter anyways, just checked the JSON specs. See answer below.

Comment: You really should fix the code that produces the invalid JSON and wraps the array in double quotes. That value is valid JSON for string, not an array of values.

Comment: I've added the code created that Json string. Please take a look. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out. In the code which produces the Json, I should have used `JsonArray` instead of `List<Integer>`, then the library won't put the quotation mark around the array.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not valid JSON to put double quotes around array values (see language grammar at http://json.org/). Therefore your JSON parser will probably not support that.

Additional background information: your JSON defines `ProductIds` as a pair with the string value `[30, 50]`.

Comment: So what is the correct way to define it as an array of integer numbers?

Comment: Like you did, however, without double quotes around, i.e.: `...,"ProductIds":[30, 50],...`